# Ubuntu по сети откликается на старый hostname (samba)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Имеется несколько машин, крутящихся на ESXI. Старые машины имеют статические IP адреса, и hostname-ы по типу Agent1/2/3/4.На всех машинах стоит одинаковый набор ПО, в том числе samba для организации беспарольного сетевого доступа к шарам из виндовой среды. В настройках Samba hostname (netbios name) не указывается, подтягивается hostname машинки.

Из машинки Agent2 методом копирования были получены ещё 2 виртуальных машины -agent5/6 (переименованы через интерфейс убунту, на корректность изменений проверены hostname, hosts файлы). Они получают ip адреса динамически, но эти динамические адреса привязаны к mac адресам машин (нам зажали статик-пул).

Проблема в том, что иногда, по невыясненным причинам Agent6 откликается так-же на имя Agent2. То есть при попытке посмотреть в шары 2-ого агента, мы на самом деле смотрим в шары 6-ого, и до agent2 возможно достучаться только по ip. Установка в настройках samba на 6-ой машине захардкоженого netbios name = Agent6  не помогла, машина всё-ещё периодически откликается на Agent2. При этом, то, на шары какого агента мы попадём, зависит и от компа наблюдателя, то есть в одно и то-же время данная проблема наблюдается не со всех клиентов.
Соответственно, 2 вопроса.

1. Возможно ли такое из-за того, что новым машинкам зажали статические ip адреса?
2. Есть ли пути решения, без установки статических ip на машинки? Или же просто любые пути решения проблемы.

Comment: имя точно ни где не завалялось? `grep -ri Agent2 /etc` ничего интересного не даёт? поиск хостов в сети идёт только средствами netbios или DNS сервер также отвечает на запросы по тем же именам?